# Rename Javascript Confirmation message box label from Yes to Proceed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to rename the Javascript Confirmation message box label from Yes to Proceed?

Comment: easy to do with Jquery if you are using that type.

Comment: Note to those suggesting using jQuery/jQueryUI solutions - that is not a direct replacement for `confirm()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't, unless you use a library like jQueryUi which will provide an alternative : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation